# Why does pricing search return no results for item that has prices?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

SuiteScript 2 Suitelet.

In the following code, why would `count` be zero for an `itemInternalId` that has prices in the UI?

```
var searchObj = search.create({
    type: 'item',
    filters: [
        search.createFilter({
            name: 'internalid',
            operator: search.Operator.IS,
            values: [itemInternalId]
        })
    ],
    columns: [
        search.createColumn({
            name: 'unitprice',
            join: 'pricing',
        }),
        search.createColumn({
            name: 'quantityrange',
            join: 'pricing',
        }),
        search.createColumn({
            name: 'maximumquantity',
            join: 'pricing',
        }),
        search.createColumn({
            name: 'minimumquantity',
            join: 'pricing',
        })
    ]
});

var count = searchObj.runPaged().count;
```

`itemInternalId` is of a matrix child item and `count` is zero.

If I set `itemInternalId` to its sibling matrix child item then `count` is greater than zero.

Both items appear to have identical pricing configured in the UI.

Comment: Is this a matrix item? Is the iteminternalid the parent item id?

Comment: Both items are matrix children

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `search.Operator.ANYOF` in your search filters.